# Implementing Support Vector Machines in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement SVM classification for text  in Android . Can anybody suggest me that from where I can get the Idea about implementing in Android . i.e.  Some books or some online reading material related to it .

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The implementation in android is very similar at the implementation in phyton. I suggest you to read this link http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-train-auto and follow the parameters and methods of python. Hope this help you.
Marco

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the things into vector space model and also there is open source implementation of support vector machine in php along with clear explanation.

http://phpir.com/support-vector-machines-in-php

And also if you are familier with java it would not be an issue to implement it in android.
below is the implementation of svm in java.
https://github.com/encog/libsvm-java/blob/master/svm-train.c